# Query for Postgres value without key in nested JSON

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgres-9.6

I am trying to query for a value inside a nested JSON with it's corresponding key but the problem is the preceding key is unknown. How can we do this in Postgres?

Here I need to query for the value of "status" but the keys "random1" and "random2" are not constant.

Let's say this is the sample value in "my_table" and column "my_jsonb"

my_jsonb:

```
{
  "known": {
    "random1": {
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    "random2": {
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    "random3": {
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

ACTIVE
ACTIVE
ACTIVE

I want to look for values of all "status" keys without specifying preceding key.

Comment: Please show us the the result that you expect as tabular text. Do you just want one record or more?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
select value, value->>'status' from json_each(json_object->'known')
```

Best regards,
Bjarni